# CameraPivot moves when the head is standing still

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make the camera follow the character's head (character with animations). Pivot is attached to the head and in the pivot is the camera. The only thing that affects the camera is its rotation with the mouse, the position of the camera does not change in any way. For some reason I have Pivot changes its position when the position of the head does not change (the head changes only rotation due to animation) and because of this the camera shakes a lot during animations. (The player script itself rotates **the camera** and the character along the Y axis, I tried to make the rotation of the pivot'a - nothing changed).

`FollowHead.cs`

```
public class FollowHead : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform headTransform;

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (headTransform != null)
        {
            transform.position = headTransform.position;
        }
    }
}
```

`hierarchy`

*Character Controller -> char (mesh) -> Armature -> Hips -> Spine -> Spine2 -> Neck -> Head -> CameraPivot (with script) -> Camera*

[hierarchy pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKHsd.png)